# What is the volume of a hyper cylinder in d - dimension?

Tags: geometry, volume

Is it $L \times S^{d-1}$ where $S$ is the hyper sphere of $d-1$ dimension and $L$ is length in usual 1 dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The volume of the Cartesian product of two sets is the product of volumes. The familiar solid cylinder is the Cartesian product of a two-dimensional ball $B^2$ and a line segment $L$. Consequently, its volume is $|B^2|\cdot |L| =  \pi r^2 h$.

In $n$ dimensions, one can define cylinders as products $B^{n-1}\times L$ and get the volume formula $|B^{n-1}|\cdot |L|$. See Wikipedia for the [volume of $B^{n-1}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball).